# Criação de ForeignKey

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Bom, no meu projeto eu resolvi utilizar algumas Foreign Keys. E depois de acabar obtendo esse erro :

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Setors_dbo.Areas_setorAreas\". The conflict occurred in database \"RamalAguia.Models.RamaDb\", table \"dbo.Areas\", column 'areaID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Percebi que na minha *Table* aparecia uma *Foreign Key* que eu não estava criando e que não tinha relação com o meu projeto atual. Mas até ai tudo o bem, o problema foi que mesmo após atualizar a database e deletar essa FK toda vez que eu executava o meu projeto ela reaparecia.

Meus Models

**Setor**

```
public class Setor
{
    [Key, Column(Order =1 )]
    public int setorID { get; set; }

    public string setorName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Area"), Column(Order = 3)]
    public int areaID { get; set; }

    public Area Area { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("SetorId")]
    //public ICollection<RamalModel> RamalModel { get; set; }
}
```

**Table do model Setor**

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Setors] (
   [setorID]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [areaID]    INT            NOT NULL,
   [setorName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Setors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([setorID] ASC),
   //Essa linha de baixo cria um FK que eu não peço onde eu não tenho esse "setorAreas"
   CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Setors_dbo.Areas_setorAreas] FOREIGN KEY ([areaID])     REFERENCES [dbo].[Areas] ([areaID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Setors_dbo.Areas_areas_areaID] FOREIGN KEY ([areaID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Areas] ([areaID])
   );

   GO
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_areaID]
   ON [dbo].[Setors]([areaID] ASC);
```

**Area**

```
  public class Area
{
    [Key, Column(Order=3)]
    public int areaID { get; set; }

    public string areaNome { get; set; }
}
```

**Table do Model Area**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Areas] (
[areaID]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[areaNome] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Areas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([areaID] ASC)
);
```

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Várias coisas erradas, e faltando algumas. Vou começar por `Setor`:

```
[TableName("Setores")] // Use isto para definir corretamente o nome da tabela.
                       // A inflexão em inglês pluraliza errado o nome.
public class Setor
{
    // [Key, Column(Order =1 )]
    [Key] // Se não é chave composta, não use `Column`.
    public int SetorId { get; set; } // Procure usar TypeCase, conforme a convenção do EF. Apenas primeiras letras de palavras são maiúsculas.
    // [ForeignKey("Area"), Column(Order = 3)]
    public int AreaID { get; set; } // [ForeignKey] não precisa ser usada aqui. O EF é capaz de deduzir a chave estrangeira sozinho.

    // public string setorName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // Aqui não é exatamente um erro, mas não tem necessidade de você dizer que o Nome é do Setor.

    public virtual Area Area { get; set; } // Especifique virtual para apontar para o EF que é ele que deve preencher a propriedade.
}
```

E `Area`:

```
public class Area
{
    // [Key, Column(Order=3)]
    [Key] // Não use Column dentro de Key se a chave não for composta.
    public int AreaID { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Setor> Setores { get; set; } // A relação entre Setor e Area é de 1 para N, então você precisa dizer isso ao EF.
                                                            // Aqui é a origem do seu erro.
```

Se você fez tudo o que passei, suas tabelas ficarão assim:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Setores] (
    [SetorId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AreaId]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [Nome] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Setores] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SetorId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Setores_dbo.Areas_Area_AreaId] FOREIGN KEY ([AreaId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Areas] ([AreaId])
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AreaId]
ON [dbo].[Setores]([AreaId] ASC);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Areas] (
    [AreaId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Areas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AreaId] ASC)
);
```